# Create Table Syntax Error - MS Access, SQL view

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I keep getting CREATE TABLE Syntax Error, but I don't see the error!  What is causing the error?

**My SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE my_employee
(
employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
birthdate DATE,
salary NUMERIC(8,2) DEFAULT 15000,
marital_status CHAR(1)
);
```

Comment: Does the error message give you any more information?

Comment: No, just simply 'CREATE TABLE Syntax Error'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your DDL statement includes `DEFAULT`, you must execute it with ADO.  I loaded your statement into a string variable and executed it from Access 2007 like this:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

The *salary* field is decimal with precision 8, scale 2, and default 15000.

`DEFAULT` is one of the Access SQL features added with Jet 4.0.  Those features are not available for a statement executed from DAO.  If you are using Access' query designer to create and execute the statement, you're using DAO.  Same if you were using `CurrentDb.Execute`.  But `CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO object, so it can `.Execute` Jet 4.0 features.

Note `NOT NULL` is not necessary after `PRIMARY KEY` since `PRIMARY KEY` implies `NOT NULL`.   However `PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` does not trigger an error.  The statement works as you originally wrote it as long as you execute it from ADO.

Comment: LOL I am a student and the teacher is showing us the basics of Access and he told me to use DEFAULT. But unfortunately because of the perimeters of the project, I can only execute from DAO. Still, you found an answer so I am upvoting! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well I was having the same problem with Ms Access 2007, but I solved it later on.
It is because actually some features are disabled by default for security reasons over there.
When it shows you `syntax error`, you can see the message at menu bar somewhere or at the bottom: `Some Features Are Disabled For Security Reasons...`.
Click on the message then proceed to enable further features.

Answer (score 1):

As HansUp said: "default" in DDL doesn't work here. As an alternative you can create the table without the default first and add the default via the TableDef afterwards:

```
CurrentDb().Execute "create table my_employee ..."
CurrentDb().TableDefs("my_employee").Fields("salary").DefaultValue = 15000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your PRIMARY KEY declaration

```
CREATE TABLE my_employee
(
employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
birthdate DATE,
salary NUMERIC(8,2) DEFAULT 15000,
marital_status CHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);
```

Comment: I tried that earlier - unfortunately I still get the syntax error